# 2 dynmically created spinners -> but only 1 onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

i got 2 dynamically created spinners in 1 Activity.

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View SpinnerLayout = adbInflater2.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
    adb2.setView(SpinnerLayout);
    adb2.setTitle("Kostenstelle auswählen:");
    spinnerKOST = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
    lables.add("");
    spinnerKOST.setSelection(1, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < KostList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(KostList.get(i).getKost());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerKOST.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    // use .create to get the AlertDialog 
    AlertDialog dialog =  adb2.create();
    // set an OnShowListener
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            spinnerKOST.setOnItemSelectedListener(StaffActivity.this);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();       
}
```

and the second:

```
private void populateSpinner2() {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View SpinnerLayout = adbInflater2.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
    adb2.setView(SpinnerLayout);
    adb2.setTitle("Box auswählen:");
    spinnerBox = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
    lables.add("");
    spinnerBox.setSelection(1, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < BoxesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(BoxesList.get(i).getBoxer_mail());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerBox.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    AlertDialog dialog =  adb2.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            spinnerBox.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) StaffActivity.this);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();       
}
```

they are pretty the same, as you see.

Normally I use for every spinner 1 `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

Before I only had 1 Spinner per Activity and 1 `public void onItemSelected`.
Now I got 2 Spinner in the Activity but still 1  `public void onItemSelected`.

How I can use both spinners?

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two spinner and toggle view viible and invisible between them

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
 if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
 {
      //spinner1            
 }
 else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
 {
      //spinner2
 }

}
```

Comment: I saw that in another question, but it didnt helped me. I got the same R.id.spinner for both Spinner (same Layout). This doesnt help me

Comment: problem is you are referring two Spinner variable to one spinner. So use two spinner and check when you have to populate spinner1 set the visibility of spinner2 to invisible and vice-versa

Comment: I try that, but Spinnerlayout is my standard layout, which I use in the whole app. The Spinners are created dynamically and never shown up at the same time. Isnt there any other possibility?